# Function needs to return Rest Call response as JSON object. How to set the response to a variable so that it can be return as variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest-client, node-rest-client

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
module.exports = {
getWeatherStatus: function() {
        var messageData =  "";
        client.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pune&appid=123234234234243242", function (data, response) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            messageData=data;
        });
        //how to set the response of that rest call to this messageData object
        return messageData;
    }
}
```

this method getWeatherStatus should return the rest response in json format.

***Open for totally different suggestion to implement this kind of scenario. 
My basic requirement is to use this REST call response and send to other functions.***

Answer (score 0):

Since get is callback function so you have to put your  return messageData
in stead of  messageData=data.

Code should be like

```
 var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
module.exports = {
  getWeatherStatus: function() {
    var messageData =  "";
    client.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pune&appid=123234234234243242", function (data, response) {
        return  JSON.parse(data);
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getWeatherStatus` you use async function `client.get`. You need wait result from async function and only than return messageData. For this you can use [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync). Example:

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
module.exports = {
  getWeatherStatus: function() {
    var messageData =  "";
    client.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pune&appid=123234234234243242", function (data, response) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      messageData=data;
    });
    //We waiting for data.
    while (messageData === "") {
      require('deasync').sleep(10);
    }
    return messageData;
  }
}
```

But, maybe, you should return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), not data.

Comment: I can't understand why you are using sleep while it is callback function.

Comment: see https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync. It will pause node process becasue sleep is now sync. However, i would never recommend that sort of things.

Comment: Why we need to pause a code? While we can do this by just placing our processing code inside get function

Comment: because he would like ot return, it s a sync call, not async.

Comment: I am not much aware of Nodejs. What should be the best practice to implement this sort of scenario.
My basic requirement is to get the output from this rest call and need to do some manipulation on that before showing it on screen.

Comment: I think you must learn about async and sync function.It will really  help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing difficulties to deal with with callbacks,

In the method `getWeatherStatus`, instead of returning the result, you should pass it to a callback function once the treatment is done.

If really you are required to return, galk.in answer seems to be a possible way.

Otherwise, check this out,

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
module.exports = {
  getWeatherStatus: function(then) {
    var messageData =  "";
    client.get("/some/url", function (data, response) {
        then(err=null, JSON.parse(data));
    });
  }
}
```

So you may call getWeatherStatus in such way,

```
// Somewhere else in your code
getWeatherStatus(function fnCallback(err, jsonData) {
  console.log(jsonData) // process data here
})
```

As suggested, Promise are also a good alternative. but it is still async.